# Logging out Sinch user

Tags: swift, sinch

Trying to incorporate Sinch in my app and need a log out feature because my app will be shared across different users on the same device. At the moment, the same device will also receive calls made to the old users.

I was looking at this bit of the code

```
func logOutSinchUser() {
    if let client = self._client {
        client.stopListeningOnActiveConnection()
        client.unregisterPushNotificationDeviceToken()
        client.terminateGracefully()
    }
    self._client = nil
}
```

But not sure how and where to implement this... in Appdelegate? As an extension? Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Logout in SINCH not work! The app still receive call even if you are logout in SINCH! i found a solution not the best but its work on me
 In didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload you need to get the remote_Id from header

```
   func managedPush(_ managedPush: SINManagedPush!, didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload payload: [AnyHashable : Any]!, forType pushType: String!) {

    if pushType == "PKPushTypeVoIP" {
        let result = SINPushHelper.queryPushNotificationPayload(payload)
        if result?.isCall() != nil {
            if let aHeaders = result?.call().headers {
                callerIdz = aHeaders["to"] as? String
                self.handleRemoteNotification(userInfo: payload as NSDictionary)
            }
        }
    }
}//END
```

and in handleRemoteNotification check if the localUser (the user who logged in device) is the same of remote_Id if it is you need to show the notification of call and if not you will ignore this notification!

```
    func handleRemoteNotification(userInfo: NSDictionary) {

    if _client.userId != callerIdz {
        print("Not match")
        return
    } else {
        let result = self._client.relayRemotePushNotification(userInfo as! [AnyHashable : Any])
        if result!.isCall() {
                print("handle call notification")
            }
            if result!.isCall() && result!.call().isCallCanceled{
                self.presentMissedCallNotificationWithRemoteUserId(userId: result!.call()!.callId)
            }
        }
}//END
```